# How can I make another div scroll to my current div on click

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Have a column of images each underneath one another. I also have a div to the right of that column that have several notes(basically paragraphs). When you click each image a set of new notes appear. Ideally as you scroll down the page and click each image I would like the div on the right to scroll down and match up with each image that is click. I wrote a function but I can only make the entire page scroll to the top but what I need is the opposite. I'm using scrollTop: which is causing the problem I think but there isn't a scrollTo function? Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id='main'>
 ...content...
</div>

 <div id='rightnav'>
 ...content...
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('html, #rightnav').animate({
     scrollTop: $($current_image).offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `.animate()` just to the nav DIV itself. And animate just the "top" style.
For example this code:

```
$('#main img').click(function() {

    $('#rightnav').animate({top: $(this).offset().top}, 2000)

})
```

will bring DIV with ID = "rightnav" to the same top coordinates as image clicked inside of "main" DIV.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vSfP9/1/

Comment: Yurly Thank you for this answer. I have to test it out hopefully later today but from your demo it appears to be exactly what I was looking for. Once I try it out I will select correct answer, thanks again.

Comment: Hey I tried to implement this code but nothing is happening. I also get no console errors and I've put a console.log and it's definitely firing so I'm not sure what the problem is. I would normally say it has to do with the logic but your fiddle proves that it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery selectors select correctly (ids, classes, elements). Most likely jQuery is not finding needed items. If the issue still happening - can you post (perhaps abbreviated) real HTML markup in question?

Comment: The problem was with my CSS I didn't have a position explicitly set to #rightnav. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it is finally working for you :) it was an interesting project